# Hepa 13 Filter Surface Area for Given CFM

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow, fluid-filtration

How much (area) of HEPA 13 filter should I use for a blower with 160 CFM rating. I am planning to DIY a filter to match my blower's CFM rating.

Disclaimer: I'm just a hobbyist with limited education. Would love to have "rule of thumbs" type of answer, but an ELI5 is appreciated.

*EDIT: Added my goal.*

Comment: The rule of thumb is to spec existing filters for form factor and cfm rating.  Different types will have different CFM ratings.

Comment: Thanks @Tiger Guy, If my assumption is correct, you may be referring to a fully built HEPA filter. If I am to DIY my own, are you saying that HEPA 13 filter elements may have different CFM ratings? I was under the impression that HEPA 13 is a standard.